# failed: id is not defined while parsing unsing mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

So I am trying to parse some data using mongoose my schema looks like

```
data: [{

    'order-id': String,
    'sku': String,
    'purchase-date': String,
    'payments-date': String,
```

and I am trying to get the data using :

```
let parseddata = new ParsedDataModel(doc) ;
parseddata.data[0].order-id // failed id is not defined
```

While

```
parseddata.data[0].sku // is working
```

Is this a problem with the dash 6 ? How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your "dash".

Node js thinks it is a "minus" and your `id` is another variable.

Try using the following:

```
parseddata.data[0]["order-id"]
```

**PS:** I would recommend using `ObjectId` as the type for `order-id` instead of `String`. You can then populate the order document directly from this itself.